# Extend working distance on macro lenses?

Tags: macro, macro-lenses

Is it possible to extend the working distance on macro lenses? I will be renting a 100mm 2.8L and Canon 1.4x III (for a different lens), but it sounds like I cannot use the extender on the 100mm. Is this true? Is there any other way to open up the working distance of the 100mm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a third-party teleconverter like the ones branded Kenko, Tamron, or Soligor. Unlike Canon or Sigma ones, these do not have a protruding front part that needs to slot into a corresponding airgap at the rear of the lens it is mounted to.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the Canon 2x extender with my 100 2.8L macro, combined with extension tubes.  I used it for increasing the maximum magnification, but I supposed you could also use it to achieve the same magnification at a greater working distance.